# Open 2 bootstrap dropdown within single parent dropdown class but 2 different dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown menu items under single parent dropdown class. But when I click dropdown action 1 then it is showing the body of dropdown menu 2 items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdown Example</h2>
  <p>The <strong>toggle</strong> method toggles the dropdown.</p>

  <div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example 1
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu2" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example 2
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </div><br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> For dropdowns, you should always include the data-toggle="dropdown" attribute. Do not rely solely on the toggle method, as it may not work as expected in all browsers.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajay1008/jumpgkfc/

So I want to open their respective body dropdown-menus.

Comment: Why don't you simply have two `dropdown` divs?

Comment: No, I want it like mentioned above, I have a different scenario for my real application, this is just the demo of How I want.

Comment: I don't think you can have two different dropdowns under a single `dropdown`div. But, you can actually create sub dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must wrap each dropdown button in another .btn-group.

```
 <div class="btn-group">  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" open'">Dropdown Example 1
<span class="caret"></span></button>...</div>
```

mycode(you can copy this code):
https://jsfiddle.net/rezajafari2a/c1yw3hbv/

Comment: Yes, It helped, Thank you :)